# Popup in power BI via python scripts using input() function

Tags: python, input, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

we are trying to get popup in POWER BI using  python input() function, where user can provide the input and then scripts will load the data for particular business unit.

[image: This, we are trying in power BI]

[image: This we want while loading data in POWER BI via python scripts]

Thank you in advance for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a popup, you can use the in-built tkinter library [simpledialog](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html) module.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
root = tkinter.Tk()
# hide the root window because we only want to show dialogs
root.withdraw()
value = simpledialog.askinteger("My Title", "Enter an integer")
print(f"Value entered {value}")
```

This will show a popup looking like:

[image: tkinter.simpledialog.askinteger]

Comment: Hello @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2280890/import-random, The solution is working fine. Thank you so much

Comment: @RahulK I'm glad you found my answer helpful. You can see the documentation for [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You might also find it beneficial to take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get the most out of Stack Overflow.